# Can Server check if browser supports compression?

Tags: php, browser, compression

Is it possible for my php server to check if a client browser supports gzip or deflate compression? If so how to do so?

Comment: Yes, look at the `Accept-Encoding` request header: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`

Comment: Ref this - http://www.apphp.com/tutorials/index.php?page=gzip-and-deflate-compression-in-web-development

Comment: No, the server will know whether the browser accepts (or wants) compression through the headers that were sent in the request. The server doesn't specifically ask the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the browser will always send an `Accept-Encoding` header <sup>*[WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)*</sup> that contains a comma-separated list of supported compression methods. Most will look like this:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

To see if gzip (or brotli) is supported you can simply check if it appears in the header: (PHP >8)

```
if (str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) { 
    // Browser supports gzip
}
```

Comment: Added this as this question was the first one on google

Answer (score -2):

```
  # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

 #
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```